# Rearrange array values to "root level"

Tags: php, arrays

Given the following array

```
array(
  0 => array(
    'id' => '54'),
  1 => array(
    'id' => '11'),
  2 => array(
    'id' => '2')
);
```

Is there a (preferrably built-in) function that re-arranges it to

```
array(
  0 => '54',
  1 => '11',
  2 => '2'
);
```

in PHP?

My current way is to iterate over the array and save it to another one, which seems awfully redundant, slow, and inefficient.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($oldArray as $innerArray {
    $newArray[] = $innerArray['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `array_walk`

```
function array_flatten( &$item ){
    $item = $item['id'];
}

array_walk( $array, 'array_flatten' );
```

Comment: This looks neat and simple and even performant -- I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: ... ps, this won't work on nested arrays (more than 1 level); for nested arrays you'll need a recursive solution such as that posted by Sarfraz

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$arr = array(
  0 => array(
    'id' => '54'),
  1 => array(
    'id' => '11'),
  2 => array(
    'id' => '2')
);
$newArr = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive',$arr);
print_r($newArr['id']);
```